# Android translation texts not showing on app

Tags: android, string, localization, translation

In my app I support 2 languages: **English** and **Hebrew**. I created a file `strings.xml` inside the folder `values/` and there are all the English strings. I also created a file `strings.xml` inside `values-he/` folder with the **hebrew** translations.
But when opening the app in a phone which locale is **Israel/hebrew**, the user doesn't receives the translation, but only the **English** texts..
Is there something I'm missing? Do I have to do another thing?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only you need the folder

```
values-he
```

You also need the folder

```
values-iw
```

Because some devices recognize **he**, some others **iw**.
So, put the very same files in both folders and you'll have no problems.

Comment: Yes, the very same files - only the folder is choosen in a different way, depending on the device.